# Pass and read array from state in NavigationMixin.Navigate

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, navigationmixin.navigate

I am trying to find a way to pass data when navigating from page 1 to page 2 using `NavigationMixin.Navigate`. Below is the sample code that is part of a POC:

Page 1:
HTML

```
<template>
    <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Go To Next Page" onclick={navigateToNextPage} class="slds-m-left_medium"> </lightning-button>
</template>
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement, wire, api } from 'lwc';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
export default class Navigator_firstpage extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    @api someRecIds = [];
    
    navigateToNextPage(){
        for(let i=0; i<10; i++){
            this.someRecIds.push(i);
        }
        let storeState = this.someRecIds;
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__navItemPage',
            attributes: {
                apiName: 'second_page'
            },
            state: {
                filterName: 'xyz' 
            }
        }); 
    }
}
```

2nd Page:

```
<template>
    <lightning-card>
        This is 2nd page
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

JS

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import {CurrentPageReference} from 'lightning/navigation';
export default class Second_page extends LightningElement {
   // Is there a way to read the data from the state that was passed from the previous page?
   // I could not get the state in CurrentPageReference
   // OR is there any better way to pass the array when navigating?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible at the moment. I usually have my components in a wrapper component and hide/display, instead of navigating, using `if` templates in HTML. And I pass the data from one component to the other via events and event handlers.

**Note:** You are reassigning the value of public property and should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

on the second page do this

```
 @wire(CurrentPageReference)
    setCurrentPageReference(currentPageReference) {
        this.currentPageReference = currentPageReference;
        if (this.currentPageReference) {
           this.filterName = this.currentPageReference.state.filterName;
    }
    }
```

see if it helps.